# CSS menu - center align items and middle align vertically

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS menu with sub menus, i am trying to get it to display the menu items in the centre of the menu.

i tried adding `text-align:center` to `#menu-product-categories > li {` but that didn't work.

I have also added `margin-top:10px;` to `#menu-product-categories > li {` to put the text of the menu items in the middle (vertically) of the menu but when hovering on the items, the hover background does not display the full height.

I have created a fiddle here of my menu: https://jsfiddle.net/j0x39owh/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```css
.menu-product-categories-container {
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 height:60px;
 background:#F36F25;
}
#menu-product-categories, ul.sub-menu {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
    
    /** here ---------------------------- **/
  
    text-align:center;
    height:100%;
}
#menu-product-categories > li {
    /*display: inline-block;
 margin-right:0px;
 position:relative;
 padding:8px;
 text-decoration:none;
    margin-top:10px;*/
    /** here ---------------------------- **/
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
 padding:21px 8px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
#menu-product-categories li > a {
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
#menu-product-categories > li:hover {
 background:#FFFFFF;
 color:#F36F25;
}
#menu-product-categories > li > a:hover {
 color:inherit;
}
#menu-product-categories ul.sub-menu {
 display:none;
 width:200px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:1;
 left:0;
 top:40px;
}
#menu-product-categories li:hover ul.sub-menu {
 display: block;
 max-height: 200px;
 background:#F36F25;
}
#menu-product-categories ul.sub-menu li {
 color:#FFFFFF;
 float:none;
 padding:5px;
}
#menu-product-categories ul.sub-menu li:hover {
 color:#F36F25;
 background:#000000;
 float:none;
 padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-product-categories-container"><ul id="menu-product-categories" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-2933" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat current-menu-item menu-item-2933"><a href="/shop/product-category/desk-phones/">Desk Phones</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2934" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-2934"><a href="/shop/product-category/headsets/">Headsets</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2931" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-2931"><a href="/shop/product-category/conference-phones/">Conference Phones</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2932" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-2932"><a href="/shop/product-category/dect-phones/">Dect Phones</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2935" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-2935"><a href="/shop/product-category/routers/">Routers</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2936" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-2936"><a href="/shop/product-category/switches/">Switches</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2930" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-2930"><a href="/shop/product-category/cctv/">CCTV</a></li>
</ul></div>
```